# Top tags don't work correctly in Teams

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, stack-overflow-for-teams

For example, when I click one of the tags in the "Top Tags" list on my Teams profile for one of my teams, and the tag is called `python` and has ID **16**, my user ID being **51***, instead of searching for `user:51 [python]`, it searches for `user:51 [16]`. This, obviously, doesn't work.

IMHO, this is a very annoying issue that makes stuff more difficult for those who want to see a user's contributions in their top tags.

<sup>*Not necessarily my actual ID or tags in my Team.</sup>

Comment: I recall dealing with this bug some time ago (I think it was during the beta), but weird that it never has been found/reported and therefore fixed properly, as I cannot repro it on my site.